# How can I display sql query from database?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to display sql query on page in drupal 8.2, but I get an error:

> The controller must return a response (Object(Drupal\Core\Render\Markup) given).

How should I change the following code?

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, discipline, teacher FROM canteach")) {
  $output .= "Select вернул " . $result->num_rows . " строк <br />";
}

$mysqli->close();

$header = array('id', 'Discipline', 'Teacher');
$rows = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  $rows[] = array($row->id, $row->discipline, $row->teacher);
}

$result->close();

$items_array = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#items' => array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows),
);

return render($items_array);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It seems you are mixing up Drupal 8 code with Drupal 7 code, and plain PHP code. Drupal 8 code doesn't use `fetch_array()` or `MYSQLI_NUM` (nor does Drupal 7). Plus, you are not even showing the rest of the code, so we cannot know which method is using the code you are showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, I assume your code is in a controller? In that case, take note that you should return a render array or an object inheriting the Response class, not HTML.

In your case, just do:

```
return $items_array;
```

instead of

```
return render($items_array);
```

**But wait!**

The table render array should be constructed this way:

```
$items_array = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header, 
  '#rows' => $rows,
);
```

For a reference of what you can pass in, check out https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21table.html.twig/8.1.x

**Other notes**

The way you are querying data is not wrong per se but definitely not the "Drupal way". To perform queries using Drupal's DBAL, check out https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x